# Accessing Append to Array properties

Tags: power-automate, power-platform

I'm new at power automate. Im puzzled about accessing property or value from Append to array variable like the "pr_no" using variables('PRNoRows')[value]['pr_no'] but i can't get it done. Please see below the result of the array. I am gladly happy if someone knows any approaces on how to get the properties of the array. Thank you.

```
{
"name": "PRNoRows",
"value": {
    "@odata.context": "https://asia-001.azure-apim.net/apim/sql/409448f6faf34be39bbfc/$metadata#datasets('default%2Cdefault')/tables('%5Bdbo%5D.%5BvwithPayment%5D')/items",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "",
            "ItemInternalId": "906fe260-c67a-49fb-a32e-f6facf75c907",
            "id": 8259,
            "control_number": "P-CR003920",
            "cr_date": "2021-12-13T00:00:00Z",
            "company_id": 1,
            "code_count": 3920,
            "cr_no": "CR# 03320",
            "pr_no": "25342",
            "pr_date": "12/10/2021"
           
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The value property has [], which means it is an array within an array. You can use an index to retrieve the pr_no of a specific item of the array.

Try the following expression (this will retrieve the pr_no value of the first item in the value property of the first item in your array variable)

```
variables('PRNoRows')[0]['value'][0]['pr_no']
```